# Changing file extension case in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, file-extension, renaming

We have .txt files sent by users which are encrypted. We decrypt them and send it to a 3rd party system downstream as input. It had been working well but users started to send files are .TXT instead of .txt. It doesn't make any difference during decryption but it is affecting the downstream system. We are supposed to change the .TXT to .txt

I tried changing it this way

```
Copy-Item -Path $myOfile –Destination ([io.path]::ChangeExtension($myOfile, '.txt')) -Verbose
```

Here $myOfile is my file name and it named something like this
`20160506_205400_Sender_header.TXT.GPG` which we decrypt and it changes to `20160506_205400_Sender_header.TXT`

I used the above command to change it to `20160506_205400_Sender_header.txt` and it throws the below error

```
Copy-Item : Cannot overwrite the item C:\Sender\Submit\20160506_205400_Sender_header.TXT with itself.
```

It appears as if there is no distinction between .TXT and .txt. Is there a way to do it or a workaround?

Comment: you could change the extension to something else (tmp) then back to txt. *edit: this worked for me: `dir *.txt | % {ren $_.fullname ($_.name.substring(0, $_.name.length - 3) + 'txt')}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows is not case-sensitive when it comes filepaths, so a copy-operation with the same destination and source will fail because you're reading the file your trying to replace.

Use `Rename-Item` to rename files. Ex:

```
Rename-Item -Path $myOfile -NewName ([io.path]::ChangeExtension($myOfile, '.txt')) -Verbose
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Frode. I've tried that already. It isnt changing the case of the extension. That is why I had to resort to Copy-Item.

Comment: It works fine for me.. Did you remember to hit F5 in File explorer after renaming it? Be aware that `Get-Childitem -Filter "test.TXT" | Select-Object -Expand Name` will always show TXT for some reason. Try with a wildcard (or without a filter) when you verify after renaming `Get-ChildItem -Filter "Test*" | Select-Object -Expand Name`.

Comment: Ahh - Got it. It worked. Didnt realize I had to refresh it. Thanks a lot sir!